# fibonacci works in python but fails in Java

Tags: java, python, fibonacci

I have this code for calculating `fibonacci` number in `python`. It works and gives the expected result. but when I translated the same to `Java`, it fails. Any idea of what is going wrong here?

In `python`:

```
def fib3(n): 
  a,b=0,1
  while n>0:
      a,b=b,a+b
      n-=1
  return a
```

`fib3(12) --> 144`

In `Java`:

```
 public static int fib2(int n){
        int a = 0;
        int b =1;
        while(n-- >0){
            a=b;
            b=a+b;

        }
    return a;
}
```

`fib2(12) --> 2048`

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that the line `a=b` changes the value of `a` before computing `a + b` in the next line.

Comment: Nothing to do with python or java. Also in python `a = b; b = a+b` won't work as expected.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this section:

```
a=b;
b=a+b;
```

you're assigning `b` to `a+b`, but `a` is already `b`. So really you're doubling `b`

Easiest solution is a temp variable:

```
public static int fib2(int n){
    int a = 0;
    int b =1;
    while(n-- >0){
        int old_a;
        old_a = a;
        a=b;
        b=old_a+b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

In python, `a, b = b, a + b` stores an intermediate `tuple` automatically before assigning the new values to the variables, while in Java you need to be explicit about it

Breaking down Python's instructions, `a, b = b, a + b` is executing this disassembly:

```
  5          17 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             20 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             23 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             26 BINARY_ADD
             27 ROT_TWO
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             31 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
```

In a simpler sense, staying python, here's the process:

```
temp_tuple = (b, a + b)
a, b = temp_tuple
```

Comment: bah! you beat me by 13 seconds

Comment: can you elaborate the itermediate tuple part a little. I guess that has confused me..

Comment: certainly. i've updated the answer with some more information

Comment: And I didn't have chance to write answer. Anyway, may I suggest 1 edit? Define old_a inside while. It has no use outside the scope.

Comment: @BikasVaibhav, I have followed your suggestion. I don't know Java well, so am unsure of its implications. Is `old_a` now scoped to within `while`? If so, is it re-created in each loop or just on the first pass?

Comment: Yes it's recreated every time while loop runs, and destroys once it completes.

Comment: Doesn't that seem **less** efficient then?

Comment: @mhlester It has at worst a negligible impact on performance. It is generally good practice to declare a variable in the scope it is used, however, as it makes code more easily understood (you don't even need to think about what a_old might be used for outside the loop, since it is out of scope there).

Comment: @mhlester The code won't be less efficient because compiler is witty enough to optimize it. Most probably the variable old_a won't be created at all and instead of it one of the processor registers will be used.

Comment: The answer could be: *never* copy Python code to Eclipse, make few syntax adaption, and think it could ever work

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that you've got to one value from `b` to `a` ***at the same time*** as assigning to `b` the sum of `a` and `b`. Get that simultaneous swap wrong and you get the wrong answer.

In the spirit of the Python code, I present:

```
public static int fib(int n) {
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    while (n-->0)
        b = a + (a = b);
    return a;
}
```

This does the swap effectively at the same time as the add (strictly not, but it's good enough). Note that this is *well-defined* Java, as the language defines the evaluation order of operators precisely, unlike in C and C++ (where the equivalent of the above code is permitted to make demons fly out of your nose due to being Undefined Behavior).

---

OK, if it did make you experience problems with nasal demons, I'd suggest not using that compiler in future. But you wouldn't have any assurance of getting a correct fib() function…

Comment: For the record, if I see anything that does tricks like that in code that I maintain, I _will_ refactor it into simpler (if more verbose) statements. Excessive trickiness is always a good reason to refactor!

Comment: Also, for fib(largevalue) you're often better off using something based on the Gamma function if you need speed. (I always have to look that up when I need it, which is hardly ever.)

Answer (score 6):

```
a = b;
b = a+b;
```

This computes `b = 2*b` because `a`'s value is overwritten by the time you compute the new value for `b`. Replace it with:

```
t = b;
b = a+b;
a = t
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a=b;
b=a+b;
```

... is the problem.  You need to save the old value of `a` before adding it to `b`.

Answer (score 5):

The code is not equivalent, and relies on python's ability to assign multiple primitives in one line `a,b=b,a+b`; you need a temporary variable -

```
public static int fib2(int n){
  int a = 0;
  int b =1;
  while(n-- >0){
      int t = b; // <-- to hold the original value of b.
      b = a + b;
      a = t;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: a,b=b,a+b in python works as a = b; followed by b = a+b..correct?

Comment: @eagertoLearn Almost. The result of the first expression (b) is assigned to `a` and the second expression (a+b) is assigned to `b`, but the evaluations complete before the assignments.

Answer (score 3):

In java - When you write "a=b; b=a+b;" you are essentially saying that a should be equal to be and then that (since 'a' is now equal to 'b') that 'b' should just be twice what it originally was.
There are two ways you can fix this.
1) You can either continue the function you are originally using and then create a int 'temp' to store 'a' before you change 'a'.
2) You can also do what I would rather do ( this will use a lot more time however for a algorithm like fibonacci and would generally be a terrible idea for real world applications) is use a recursive function that will call itself.

It would generally look something like the following.

```
    public static int fib2(int n){
           if(n<=0){return 0;}
           if(n<2){return 1;}
           else{ return fib2(n-1)+fib2(n-2);}
    }
```

That would probably not be the exact code but something very similar. Hope that was helpful!