# Python - fibonacci numbers

Tags: python

```
def fibonacci(x):
    a=0
    b=1
    for i in range(x-1):
        b, a = a+b, b
    return b
 x = input ("Give me the number! ")
 print "The",x,". Fibonacci number: "
 print fibonacci (x)
```

so the code is fully working, but i do not understand, the `b,a=a+b,b` line, so what is this doing there?:S

Comment: it is unpacking,   `x,y = (1,2)` `x` is 1 `y` is 2

Comment: or destructuring http://robert-lujo.com/post/40871820711/python-destructuring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python, `b, a = a + b, b` stores an intermediate `tuple` automatically before assigning the new values to the variables

Breaking down Python's instructions, `b, a = a + b, b` is executing this disassembly:

```
  5          17 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             20 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             23 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             26 BINARY_ADD
             27 ROT_TWO
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             31 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
```

In a simpler sense, here's the process:

```
temp_tuple = (a + b, a)
b, a = temp_tuple
```

<sub>This answer copied from part of another answer of mine here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21585974/3130539</sub>

Comment: More complex than what I showed, but technically correct. +1

Comment: Thanks for contributing what goes on under the hood!

Answer (score 1):

Python supports a few different forms of multiple assignment. In particular,

```
>>> a = b = c = 1
>>> a
1
>>> b
1
>>> c
1
```

and

```
>>> a, b, c, *the_rest = list(range(10))
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
2
>>> the_rest
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So what you have is equivalent to:

```
tmp = b
b = a+b
a = tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a basic swap idiom, it is basically like doing the following:

```
tmp = b
b = a + b
a = tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Python separates the right-hand side expression from the left-hand side assignment. First the right-hand side is evaluated, and the result is stored on the stack, and then the left-hand side names are assigned using opcodes that take values from the stack again.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     a, b = b, a
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 ROT_TWO             
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

It works like any other unpacking assignment.

First, a tuple consisting of the values of b and a is created. Then this tuple is unpacked into a and b, effectively swapping them.

```
>>> a=5
>>> b=6
>>> a,b = b,a
>>> a
6
>>> b
5
```

Now using this property, Fibonacci Sequence are generated.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047622/1112163

Comment: Don't forget to give attribution when copying text from [someone else's  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21047622/846892).